# Eclipse/Java SwingX Error When Attempting to Add JXPanel Component To The Palette

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I am attempting to add some Java SwingX components to an Eclipse project.

I downloaded the SwingX Latest Release

I also added the downloaded jar to the Java Build Path like this:

[image: SwingX Jar]

And then in the design view of Eclipse, I add a new component like this:

[image: Add JXControl]

However, this is where I run into problems where I receive this error in the Add Component window as shown here.

[image: Add Component Error]

So for some reason, it's not finding a Class it needs since I am getting this error:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.swingx.JXPanel

Thanks in advance.

Doug

Comment: hmm ... should work, though I remember some trouble with 1.6.3, maybe you grabbed an incomplete artefact. BTW: the latest is 1.6.5-1 and accessible via maven.java.net Ahh, just reading again: when you are using a visual builder, you'll need the swingx-beaninfo.jar as well.

Comment: this solved my problem.

Thanks kleopatra